# Cannot print page title in page.html.twig

Tags: theming

The following line in `page.html.twig` does not print the page title:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

The page title outputs using the `Page title` block, but not this piece of template code. I found the `title` variable in the documentation commented out at the top of `page.html.twig`. Does this code need to be wrapped in something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `{{ title }}` is only used in maintenance and install pages where blocks are not available. See the change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2568563

Comment: So is there any other way of printing the page title in page.html.twig instead of using the block? If the block is the only way, what would this look like in page.html.twig?

Comment: You move the title block to a region and print this region in page.html.twig.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes your overall site architecture might have **Page Title block** settings using content types or other configuration which might leave one-off cases where this doesn't allow the rendering of the block via a given region.

You *can* render the page title with:

```
<h1>{{ drupal_title() }}</h1>
```

But much better... You can call the page title block in your `page.html.twig` template this way:

```
{{ drupal_block('page_title_block') }}
```

This will render the Page Title block (which works with translations).

---

Small note that printing the Page Title block this way can have a different array structure than rendering the page title block via a region, so if you are applying a page title alter somewhere, for example, you may have to take this into consideration.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  if (array_key_exists('#markup', $variables['title'])) {
    $variables['title']['#markup'] = $value;
  }
  else if (isset($variables['title'])) {
    $variables['title'] = $value;
  }
}
```

---

But of course, you can place another instance of the Page Title block via the block admin form and configure unique display settings, as well as place it in a custom region if needed.